# Division of a deck of cards

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to divide a deck of 52 cards into two decks of 26 each? How many ways are thereto do so, ensuring that each of the two decks contains exactly 13 black and 13 red cards?

Comment: To clarify, are the two decks considered distinct?  Like, a "deck A" and a "deck B"?  Or do we not care which deck is which in the end?  In either event, this should be a routine application of binomial coefficients and/or rule of product.

Comment: Do you know about the binomial coefficients ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $52\choose 26$ ways to choose 26 cards from a 52 card deck to form a pile.  A second pile is automatically formed as a consequence.

There are ${26\choose 13}{26\choose 13}$ to chose 13 red cards and 13 black cards each from different sets of 26.

Comment: thank you! this helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the groups are not considered to be different. I mean they are not labelled to be. Now, we have got $26$ black cards and $26$ red cards in total. Suppose I call the first group $A$ (which is to contain 13 black cards) and the second one $B$ (note that this is done just for convenience of explanation, and should not be considered as different groups to be permuted at the end). So out of $26$ black cards we first choose $13$ in $$\binom{26}{13}$$ ways. Same goes for red. Now our groups have got exactly $13$ cards each, black for $A$ and red for $B$. We are left with a total of $26$ cards ($13$ of each colour) which have yet to go to the groups. Now observe that, no more black can go to group $A$ and therefore, we just pick up all the red cards and place it in group $A$ and the remaining black in $B$ in just $1$ way. Therefore, the answer should be..

$$\binom{26}{13} \binom{26}{13}$$.